# Urban Airship Android push getting "This app is not configured for iOS push"

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I'm using Urban Airship and testing using their REST API. I have `Google Cloud Messaging` connected to the Urban Airship account, and one Android device registered successfully.
I can successfully send test messages from the the interface on the Urban Airship dashboard.

But when I try using the REST API `https://go.urbanairship.com/api/push/` with the body

```
{
 "audience" :  "all" ,
 "device_types" : "all",
 "notification" : {
   "android": {
     "alert" : "This is a broadcast."
   }
 }
}
```

I get a `400 Bad Request` response with `This app is not configured for iOS push`

Any idea why?

**UPDATE:** Listing the specific device APID in the "audience" section returns the same result

Comment: I don't know the API, but it seems like you should specify something like "android" instead of "all" in "device_types" (assuming you only want to push to an Android app).

Comment: This issue still open, but I managed to send push messages with UrbanBlimp https://github.com/SimonCropp/UrbanBlimp

Answer (score 5):

What you have is correct, however you need to include the following HTTP header:

```
Accept: "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;
```

For beginner Ruby developers, it can be achieved like this:

```
req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)
req["Accept"] = "application/vnd.urbanairship+json; version=3;"
```

When, e.g., posting a notification to UrbanAirship.

Comment: Adding the `accept` header made it work for me with `device_types: "all"`. Wish it was in the docs, UA.